# Spring Social Facebook Template always return same user

Tags: spring-boot, spring-social-facebook

I am using Spring Social 2.0.2.RELEASE to provide social login with Facebook. My problem is that Spring Social always return the same first user when I use FacebookTemplate. Here the example:

```

```
@Autowired
private Facebook facebook;

@RequestMapping(value = "/facebook/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView handleFacebookLogin(HttpServletResponse response) {
//always the same user
User profile = facebook.fetchObject("me", User.class, "id", "name",   "link", "email");


return new ModelAndView("redirect:/dashboard");
}
```

```

I also have a Custom ConnectController:

```

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/connect")
public class CustomConnectController extends ConnectController {

    @Autowired
    public CustomConnectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
            ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        super(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    }

    @Override
    protected RedirectView connectionStatusRedirect(String providerId, NativeWebRequest request) {
        return new RedirectView("/facebook/login");
    }


}
```

```

If a open two browsers and try to login with different users, it always return the first one. My current solution is just copy the entire ConnectController to my app and change the behaviour. It is terrible and I hope that I am making a big mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved the problem by creating this class:

```
@Configuration
public class UniqueSessionUserID extends SocialConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
    return new UserIdSource() {

        @Override
        public String getUserId() {
        RequestAttributes request = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

        String uuid = (String) request.getAttribute("_socialUserUUID", RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);

        if (uuid == null) {
            uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        }

        request.setAttribute("_socialUserUUID", uuid, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);

        return uuid;
        }
    };
    }
}
```

Here is a link where it is explained in more detail why this is necessary:
[Spring Social Facebook more than one user](http://littlebigextra.com/how-to-fix-spring-social-facebook-one-user-per-application-problem/)